# How to use htaccess to redirect all address for a folder?

Tags: apache, .htaccess

Can some one help me modify this code. I am not sure how to modify htaccess.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on

    RewriteRule (some_folder/.*) $1 [L] # adjust the regex to what you want.

    # normal cake rules
    RewriteRule ^$ webroot/ [L]
    RewriteRule (.*) webroot/$1 [L]
 </IfModule>
```

I wanna redirect all address blog/* to blog/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want:

```
RewriteRule ^blog/?(.*)$ blog/ [L]
```

I'm not sure why you'd want to ignore part of the URL though.  Do you want to force the address to blog/ instead of a transparent redirect?  Use [R] instead of [L]

To override CakePHP redirects, you could try inserting:

```
RewriteRule ^/blog(/?.*)$ /blog$1 [L]
```

before

```
RewriteRule (.*) webroot/$1 [L]
```

Comment: i am using it inside an MVC framework. cakephp. am not sure. bcos it has its own routing and... technically any thing site.com/{anything} will be considered as a controller. so wanna sent anything blog/* to blog

Comment: why don't you write a blog controller and redirect everything from that controller?

Comment: Edited my answer, though you might also consider looking into editing routes.php or creating a controller to redirect.

Comment: @deepsat isnt it easier to allow Wordpress to handle everything with just a redirect ?

Comment: @mootinator i got this above code from a cakephp contributer itself. didnt know how to modify it to blog/ so i asked the question :D  he said we can add as many folders as possible. http://dogmatic69.com/blog/development/7-using-other-apps-with-cakephp-htaccess-config

Comment: OH, lol.  You literally do just want to replace `some_folder` with `blog`.  My regex does the same thing, but repeats itself unnecessarily  You only need the line once and it will make cake ignore the whole blog subfolder.

Comment: am sorry to ask again :d 
    RewriteRule (blog/.*) $1 [L]  some thing like that ?

Comment: Yes. `RewriteRule (blog/.*) $1 [L]`